# Application where user inputs month number 1-12 and http post returns month name isn't working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, if-statement, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2013

I have an application that asks the user to input a number 1-12 in a form field. Upon hitting a submit button they should be returned to the http post which tells them the corresponding month.

EXAMPLE: if the user inputs '9' the http post SHOULD read "the month you chose is 'September'

As of now, the post is only returning the number again, and not the string/name of the month. I know there are several ways to do this, feel free to show me an easier/quicker one, but I attempted to use if/else if statements. Here is what I have so far (using: visual studio 2013 / MVC-asp.net )

MODEL:

```
public class IterApp
    {
       public int CurrentMonth { get; set; }

    }
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public ActionResult NumberApp()
        {
            IterApp model = new IterApp();
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult NumberAppResults(IterApp ia)
        {

            return View(ia);
        }
```

VIEW NumberApp (form view):

```
<script>

        var CurrentMonth = $("#CurrentMonth").val();

        function whichMonth()
        {
            if(CurrentMonth >= 1)
            {
                CurrentMonth = "January";
            }
            else if(CurrentMonth >= 2)
            {
                CurrentMonth = "February";
            }
            else if(CurrentMonth >= 3)
            {
                CurrentMonth = "March";
            }
            else if(CurrentMonth >= 4)
            {
                CurrentMonth = "April";
            }
            else if(CurrentMonth >= 5)
            {
                CurrentMonth = "May";
            }
            else if(CurrentMonth >= 6)
            {
                CurrentMonth = "June";
            }
            else if(CurrentMonth >= 7)
            {
                CurrentMonth = "July";
            }
            else if(CurrentMonth >= 8)
            {
                CurrentMonth = "August";
            }
            else if(CurrentMonth >= 9)
            {
                CurrentMonth = "September";
            }
            else if(CurrentMonth >= 10)
            {
                CurrentMonth = "October";
            }
            else if(CurrentMonth >= 11)
            {
                CurrentMonth = "November";
            }
            else
            {
                CurrentMonth = "December";
            }
        }



    </script>

    <div>
        <br />
        <form method="post" action="NumberAppResults" onsubmit="return (whichMonth)">
            Let's start a new iteration! This time, enter the NUMBER (1-12) of the month you'd like to output:
            <br />
            <br />
            <input id="CurrentMonth" type="text" name="CurrentMonth" />
            <br/>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Which Month is it?" />

        </form>
    </div>
```

VIEW NumberAppResults (http post):

```
<span>The Month you chose is:</span>
    <span>@Model.CurrentMonth</span>
```

Comment: Eh... there's a _lot_ wrong with your code and your approach in general. You seem to be mixing up clientside and serverside. `var CurrentMonth = $("#CurrentMonth").val();` will evaluate once, upon page load.  `CurrentMonth = "December"` doesn't re-assign the input, so will still cause the numeric input to be posted. Your serverside code can't handle a string being posted anyway.

Comment: Yea, why do you need a POST?

Comment: It is kind of just a learning exercise I'm putting myself through (and learning MVC / POST / etc), thanks for all feedback guys it helps! Keep it coming if there is more to help! I was thinking a for loop approach may be wiser? Still learning it all, so I'm not suprised it's way off, but any constructive feedback is a learning experience!

Comment: in your sample here.. there is no iteration occurring here, and no need for a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I very well could be looking at this wrong, but I'm not quite sure how you're returning `CurrentMonth` as a string when it's an int in your class. That said, why not try this?

```
public class IterApp
    {
       public int CurrentMonth { get; set; }
       public string MonthName { get; set; }

    }

    public ActionResult NumberApp()
    {
        IterApp model = new IterApp();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NumberAppResults(IterApp ia)
    {
        //You might need to move this around to where it's appropriate, 
        //but this will return the name of the month for the int value
        //that you receive. The if/else you have should be unnecessary.

        ia.MonthName = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(ia.CurrentMonth);
        return View(ia);
    }
```

Basically - just add a `MonthName` property to the class, then set that value using the `DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName()` function before you return to the view.

You'll also want to update the View to use `@Model.MonthName` to display the result.

Comment: You would need to modified the *view* to use `MonthName` as well.. eh?

Comment: @BrettCaswell Correct! I edited my post to say this.

Comment: I think it should be point out that this is actually kind of bad practice... `IterApp` is taking on two responsibilities here, it's being used as a type that the framework (mvc) is using to deserialize `formdata["CurrentMonth"]` into an instance of; then, in the handling of the Post action, it is having additional properties set so it can be used to initialize/construct a view..

Comment: @BrettCaswell Can you please post a solution that you think reflects best practices? I'm still learning, too! Would be happy to see a more proper solution.

Comment: your solution is fine.. but you could just pass an anonymous type to the view `new { CurrentMonth = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(ia.CurrentMonth) }`.. again, this is just to avoid declaring/defining a property on the 'dto' (`IterApp`).  `IterApp` should only have a property for each `input` field of the form.

Comment: Worked great, thanks for the help and feedback everyone

Comment: I was incorrect, @levelonehuman .. you can't use anonymous objects in this manner.. it doesn't refect on the type properly.. you would have to use the `System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject` : http://gregshackles.com/anonymous-view-models-in-asp-net-mvc-using-dynamics/

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Globalization;
```

//exemple for january

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(1);
```

//just replace 1 with your int variable

Comment: Beat me to it! Much cleaner than a huge if/else statement :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't be computing the month name in your view if you're going to post the month integer to your controller. That should be computed in your post action. Second, once you've fixed that, you need to make the model for the view returned by your post action a string, or something that contains a string. You can't say "The Month you chose is: @Model.CurrentMonth" and expect that integer field to contain the string month name.

Comment: this should be a comment.

Comment: @user1666620 why? If he does what I told him it will fix his problem

Comment: because it is generic "how to debug your issues" boilerplate, as opposed to a concrete answer to the problem at hand.

Comment: B/c are you sure OP wants month as string on server? Or just trying to update client and doesn't need server at all?

Comment: regardless, the information helps steer me in the direction I want to be, thanks for feedback

Comment: I guess it is hard to tell, but he IS posting the month integer to the server.

Comment: For instance, return View(ia); should be return View("monthname");. The logic to get monthname should be on server side, in C#. You don't need the javascript method to figure it out. The view for NumberAppResults should have a model of string (if that's the only thing it needs).

Comment: That is pretty much what I was saying Andy

Answer (score 0):

Your code will never execute past this point:

```
if(CurrentMonth >= 1)
{
    CurrentMonth = "January";
}
else if(....)
```

instead you need to do this:

```
var CurrentMonth = whichMonth($("#CurrentMonth").val());

function whichMonth(currentMonth)
{
    switch(currentMonth)
    {
        case 1: return "January";
        case 2: return "February";
        case 3: return "March";
        case 4: return "April";
        case 5: return "May";
        case 6: return "June";
        case 7: return "July";
        case 8: return "August";
        case 9: return "September";
        case 10: return "October";
        case 11: return "November";
        case 12: return "December";
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the fact that the OP is trying to render a string month name from an integer model field.

Comment: This is cleaner this original method, but doesn't answer the question.